# How to access url parameters on View::composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I want to receive the url parameters in the method `View::composer` but I don't know how to do it...

**This is in filters.php:**

```
View::composer('profile.followers', function($view){
    dd($view->parameters);
    $view->with('menus', $menus);
});
```

**This is my route:**

```
Route::get('/outfit/{id}/{slug}', [
    'uses'      => 'PictController@view',
    'as'        => 'pict.view',
    'before'    => 'assets'
]);
```

**This is my Controller:**

```
public function followers($username){
   $d['d'] = Follow::with('followers')->where('id_user_to', 10)->get();
   $this->layout->nest('content', 'profile.followers', $d);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably check out Laravel API doc on [Router](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html), you can probably use  `Route::current()` which returns you a `Route` instance.

Then according to [Route](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) documentation, you can use `parameters()`.

For example:

```
$currentRoute = Route::current();
$params = $currentRoute->parameters();

dd($params); // Will dump the keys and values of current route parameters
```

**UPDATE**
Note that this only works on 4.1+, prior to this the method names were different.

```
// 4.1+
Route::current();
Route::parameters();

// Before 4.1
Route::getCurrentRoute();
Route::getParameters();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
View::composer('profile.followers', function($view){
   //$data contains id/slug
   $viewdata= $view->getData();
   dd($viewdata['id']);

    $view->with('menus', $menus);
});
```